# using definitions in c inefficient?

Tags: c

is using definitions in c like this:

```
#define C1 42
#define C2 10
#define finalC C1 * C2
```

inefficient as this code will be ALWAYS run during run-time even though the calculation might not be needed?

Comment: Basically, the compiler is smart and will make sure that unnecessary computations are not performed and those that are will be as efficient as possible.

Comment: The compilers are smart enough to erase simple overhead. Don't waste time on minor things.

Comment: There is literally no code shown.  There are 3 pre-processor string-replacement-definitions.  ***IF*** `finalC` is used in any code, the definition of `finalC` will be precomputed to value `420` during compile-time, and have no impact on run-time.

Comment: _this code will be ALWAYS run during run-time_  No it won't.  In the code shown, `finalC` will be computed at compile time, period.  And a macro will _never_ be less efficient than the equivalent code written out explicitly, for the reason given by @eric in his answer.  But macros can be slippery customers, so, on casual inspection, they might not expand to what you think they expand to in any given situation.  Recommendation: get into the habit of plastering your macros with brackets, `#define finalC ((C1) * (C2))`, it will save you a lot of nasty surprises down the line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> as this code will be ALWAYS run during run-time even though the calculation might not be needed?

The multiplication will most likely *not* be executed at run-time. For example, this short function:

```
#define C1 42
#define C2 10
#define finalC C1 * C2

int foo() { return finalC; }
```

may [compile](https://godbolt.org/z/5h1Y5Y6GE) into:

```
foo():
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     eax, 420
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

and that's without any optimization flags!

The macro expansion happens before the compiler processes the code; and it is allowed, and tends to, evaluate constant expressions.

<sub>PS - The compiler used was GCC 11.3 and the target architecture is x86_64.</sub>

Answer (score 4):

No reasonable compiler will multiple 42 by 10 for this code at run-time. The product, 420, will be computed during compilation (unless optimized out because it is not even needed in the final program).

The macro definitions and replacements are evaluated during program translation, not while the program is running.